# Update cookie in django without resetting expiration time

Tags: python, django, cookies, request, response

Is it possible to update cookie value, without resetting it, i need to save expiration time? Currently i try to do something like that:

```
class SetBannerCookie(object):
    def process_template_response(self, request, response):
        max_age = 60
        banners = Banner.objects.filter(active=True, show_start_date__lte=timezone.now(), show_end_date__gte=timezone.now())

        for banner in banners:
            cookie_name = 'banner_'+str(banner.id)
            if cookie_name in request.COOKIES:
                # update value only here
            else:
                response.set_cookie(cookie_name, value='yes', max_age=max_age, path='/')
        return response
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the expiration of a cookie and then update the cookie with new value while setting the remaining expiration time as the expiry.

For example we set a cookie with 60mins expiry time left. After 20 mins, it has 40 mins left. Now we can update the coookie and set expiry to be 40 mins. Thus we can keep the original expiration.

`request.META['HTTP_COOKIE']` would contain the original cookie string. We can use [`SimpleCookie`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cookie.html#Cookie.SimpleCookie) class to decode the values. Now do the calculation and update it.

Comment: I found answers like this, but there is no expiration data in request.META['HTTP_COOKIE'], also i tried SimpleCookie(request.META['HTTP_COOKIE']), it normally parse data, but there also no expiration data

Comment: @meteor What do you get when you do: `print SimpleCookie(request.META['HTTP_COOKIE'])['sessionid'].values()` ?

Comment: i got:
Set-Cookie: banner_2=yes
Set-Cookie: banner_2_status=shown
Set-Cookie: banner_3=yes
Set-Cookie: banner_3_status=shown
Set-Cookie: banner_4=yes
Set-Cookie: banner_4_status=shown
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=Upp92BdZqfMMDTTvqga0hLQtnkiFSZa3
Set-Cookie: sessionid=z99b3s0cxkqydy56ul3jxx027oj51xkk

actually i solved this problem using 2 cookies instead of one, as you can see above, but  there appeared some js work